# implementing big5 over telnet protocol?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking, telnet, big5

I've implemented a telnet client and one of the feature requests is to support big5 encoding. How is Big5 implemented over telnet, when only 7-bit character codes are supported? The Big5 "lead bytes" (0x81 to 0xfe) are all in the range above 0x7f reserved by the telnet protocol. Of course, if I took out VT100 escape code parsing and treated non telnet-escape-sequence bytes as plain big5-encoded text, that would probably work, but I don't know if that's the standard (if there even is a standard). Also, is there an equivalent to the VT100 terminal protocol for Big5 encoding?

FYI: This project is written in C# and runs on windows phone silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want RFC2066, which describes the [TELNET CHARSET Option](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2066).

Comment: Unfortunately, BIG5 is a bad choice for a protocol used over the internet, because the name BIG5 is used for [many different variants](http://haible.de/bruno/charsets/conversion-tables/Big5.html) and the variant that is most used today is CP950 from Microsoft, which is quite different from the original BIG5 from the 1990ies. UTF-8 would be a better choice.